# Аналог await Task.Delay(1000) в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

господа. Есть такое задание: разработать программу, изображающую на экране работающие электронные часы с цифровым индикатором, а также с индикацией в отдельных окнах даты и дня недели. Предусмотреть в программе установку времени, даты, дня недели, а также пуск часов.
Написал следующую функцию для хода часов:

```
 public void Tick (){
    String secBuf = TSec.getText();
    sec = Integer.parseInt(secBuf);
    sec++;
    secBuf = Integer.toString(sec);
    TSec.setText(secBuf);
        if(sec >= 60){
    String minBuf = TMin.getText();
            min = Integer.parseInt(minBuf);
            min++;
            minBuf = Integer.toString(min);
            TMin.setText(minBuf);
    sec = 0;
            secBuf = Integer.toString(sec);
            TSec.setText(secBuf);
    if(min >= 60){
                String hourBuf = THour.getText();
                hour = Integer.parseInt(hourBuf);
                hour ++;
                hourBuf = Integer.toString(hour);
                THour.setText(hourBuf);
                min = 0;
                minBuf = Integer.toString(min);
                TMin.setText(minBuf);
                if(hour >= 24){
                    hour = 0;
                    hourBuf = Integer.toString(hour);
                    THour.setText(hourBuf);
                }
    }
        }
}
```

Также есть функция, которая запускается при нажатии "Пуск часов":

```
@FXML
private void MPuskAct(ActionEvent event) {
     while(true) {
        Tick();
        try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске программы и нажатии на эту кнопку происходит коллапс, программа виснет и не отвечает. Также я пробовал писать вместо `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` такую вещь: `Thread.sleep(1000);`, но результат тот же. Покопавшись на форумах, я понял, что тут проблема в потоках, но не понимаю, как их разграничить. В С# есть `await Task.Delay(1000)`, но в Java я такого найти не смог. Можете что-то подсказать похожее?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая что в данной задаче периодически нужно менять содержимое JаvaFX-контролов, то правильнее будет использовать что-то из JavaFX, напр. javafx.animation.Timeline:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.util.Duration;

// ...

private Timeline oneSecTick;

public void initialize() {
    // ...
    oneSecTick = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> Tick()));
    oneSecTick.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
}

@FXML
private void MPuskAct(ActionEvent event) {
    oneSecTick.play();
}

private void Tick() {
    // ...
}
```

Полный запускаемый пример, все в одном классе:

```
import java.time.LocalTime; 
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class JavaFXClock extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private Timeline oneSecTick;
    private Label label;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Clock");

        oneSecTick = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> tick()));
        oneSecTick.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        label = new Label("--:--");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Start");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                oneSecTick.play();
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(16);
        root.getChildren().add(label);
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void tick() {
        label.setText(LocalTime.now().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!
Я почитал немного про Timeline, попробовал применить Ваш код, но у меня вылетает ошибка на строке oneSecTick.play();
Подозреваю, что после public void initialize() и перед oneSecTick = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), event -> Tick())) должен быть некий код, но не могу сообразить, какой. Если Вас не затруднит, не могли бы вы хотя бы подсказать направление, в котором искать?
Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Я предположил, что метод initialize уже существует (специальный метод, вызывается после установки анотированных @FXML полей), в принципе эту часть ничего не должно мешать переместить в конструктор класса. Дополнил примером с main методом, должен просто запускаться

Comment: Спасибо, я нашел свою ошибку! Часы тикают, все работает, большое спасибо! 
И еще такой вопрос, если позволите: возможно ли компоненту DatePicker посылать команду о переносе на следующий день, если часы обнулились (т. е. на часах 23:59:59, дата 01.01.2019, а когда станет 00:00:00, то дата должна стать 02.01.2019)? Или стоит как-то пытаться запрограммировать TextField на прием даты?
Еще раз спасибо Вам!

Comment: DatePicker позволяет устанавливать значение `datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.of(2019, 6, 2));` принимая экземпляр класса ` java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: Спасибо! Дальше разберусь, надеюсь)